# Divide a values among several columns based on its percentage

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, insert, percentage

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue'],
'numbers': [1, 2, 3],
'numbers1': [2, 1, 0],
'numbers3': [4, 3, 0],
'Total': [7, 6,3]})



    colors  n   n1  n3  Total
0   red     1   2   4   7
1   white   2   1   3   6
2   blue    3   0   0   3

dfpct = df.iloc[::,1:-1].div(df.Total, axis=0).fillna(0)
dfpct

numbers         numbers1    numbers3
0   0.142857    0.285714    0.571429
1   0.333333    0.166667    0.500000
2   1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

The code above gives me the percentage of each row per column.
Now I have a new total value that I would like to insert to each row based on each row percentage, in another words replace the percentage with an actual value.

The new Total value would be divided by its value in percentage and inserted in the row, or replace.

For instance the new total would be

```
Total1 = [10, 6, 8]
numbers         numbers1    numbers3
0   0.142857    0.285714    0.571429
new 14.3        2.86        5.71
and so on
```

Thanks

Comment: @enke  It does not matter dude. Lets say that new Total will be [10, 6, 8], I thought about a function to replace the numbers in the how based on the dfpct.
Lets say numbers         numbers1    numbers3
0            0.142857         0.285714     0.571429
new       1.42                 2.86             5.71

10 was an easy example

Answer (score 1):

Check with `mul`

```
out = dfpct.mul([10,6,8],axis=0)
Out[279]: 
    numbers  numbers1  numbers3
0  1.428571  2.857143  5.714286
1  2.000000  1.000000  3.000000
2  8.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: I will try it now.
Thanks

Comment: nice one mate. It works like a charm.